# Distinct as a QueryParam in lift's Mapper ORM

Tags: scala, lift, mapper

How can we use the Distinct QueryParam in finding distinct records from a DB Table. ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

MyMapper.find(By(someField, "someValue", Distinct())